# pg_restore error while initializing. (Closed)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am getting the error of:

> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while INITIALIZING:
>   pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout"
>       Command was: SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;

when i am trying to restore the data using

```
pg_restore -h 172.16.0.70 -U postgres -d newdb05aug19 -1  dirfrmt;
```

The postgres version is PostgreSQL 9.3.23

The pg_dump version is  pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.3.23

The pg_restore version is pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 9.3.23

Comment: Looks like you are either connecting to a modified fork of PostgreSQL, or the server version is less than 9.6. Please add details to the question that tell the version of `pg_dump` used to create the dump, the version of `pg_restore` used and the version of the PostgreSQL server.

Comment: Sounds as if the dump was taken from a newer (supported) version of Postgres and isn't compatible with the (unsupported) version 9.3

Comment: As you said, The dump file is from version 9.5, I faced these errors while dumping into the server containing postgres version 9.3. But, When dumped into the same or higher version it works fine. @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The pg_dump version is pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.3.23

Is that the program which was used to generate the "dirfmrt" directory?  It doesn't matter what pg_dump you have install locally, if the backup file came from somewhere else.

The version of the running postgresql server which was dumped, and the version of pg_dump used to dump it, are included in the dump.  You can see them (as comments) using something like this:

```
pg_restore dirfrmt | head -n6
```

> The pg_restore version is pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 9.3.23

While you may have that version of pg_restore installed somewhere in your system, it does not seem to be the one you are actually using to do the restore.  Whether `SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;` is emitted depends on the version of pg_restore used, and 9.3 does not emit it.

Comment: As you said, Actually this error is because of version mismatch. The backup file is from recent postgres version, And i have tried to restore it in 9.3. But, When tried in the versions 9.5 and 9.6 process was clean. Thanks for the info...!!!!